# Should I consider migrating away from OAuth 2.0 Implicit Flow for an internal application relying on Azure AD?

Tags: oauth, oauth2, active-directory, azure

I have recently migrated an internal application (API + SPA) security from Windows Authentication (done by IIS) to Azure A/D authentication using the implicit flow.

Now, every user must enter an e-mail address, password and an authentication code (typically generated by a mobile app).

The test environments also expose Swagger documentation that relies on a displayed ClientId and scope name to authenticate (user, password and code are still required).

After being done with the changes I have discovered that [OAuth 2.0 Implicit Flow is not exactly recommended for new applications](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead), but it is not clear for me if changing the flow should be a priority for me at this point:

> The important thing to remember here is that there was no new
> vulnerability found in the Implicit flow. If you have an existing app
> that uses the Implicit flow, it’s not that your app is suddenly now
> insecure after this new guidance has been published.
>
> That said, it is – and always has been – extremely challenging to
> implement the Implicit flow securely. If you have gone to the trouble
> of thoroughly auditing your source code, knowing exactly which
> third-party libraries you’re using in your application, have a strong
> Content Security Policy, and are confident in your ability to build a
> secure JavaScript application, then your application is probably fine.
>
> So should you immediately switch all your apps to using PKCE instead
> of the Implicit flow? Probably not, it depends on your risk tolerance.
> But at this point I would definitely not recommend creating new apps
> using the Implicit flow.

Source code audit was never done (just a security audit for the API endpoints), so I guess there is a potential risk when working with some third-party libraries in the SPA.

Considering that the application is an internal one (domain visible only to VPN connected users, all operations require an authenticated A/D user), should I worry about using the implicit flow or should I switch to the OAuth Authorization Code Flow asap?

Comment: What do you see going wrong if the application's authentication/authorization is circumvented? How dangerous do you think that is?

Comment: During CoVID times, when you have a lot more devices connecting from employee's home, you are likely more exposed than if it was just devices in the same physical location connected via the domain/corp net